# Replacing Windows Server 11 with NAS

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp

I have been running a Windows SBS 11 via VM Ware, it is on its last legs and I have copied the last database to a Synology NAS. In removing the server from the network I realise I will need to enable DNS and DHCP on the NAS as the server currently provides these. Is this all i will need to do to make the change, sounds all too easy. Most of the server services have been replaced by office 365 and the Cloud.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Welcome and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details (i.e. configuration files, exact error messages etc.) **and an actual question with a question mark `?`** to provide you with a good solution. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and your question closed.

Comment: One way to find out: Shut down the server and disconnect the network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should know exactly what you need to migrate and you should test it before you will irreversibly erase your old server. But if you haven't used Active Directory in your infrastructure, or you already migrated it to Azure AD, or any other alternative and you migrated your Exchange to Office365's Outlooks, so there is propably nothing more left then DNS and DHCP. Maybe be aware of a certificate store (user and also computer cert stores), look at the scheduled tasks if there is nothing you've forgotten. 
In DHCP you should look at your reservations and eventually migrate (or re-create) them to new DHCP server. In DNS you should migrate (or re-create) all your records (minus those you will not need anymore).